# Seeking advice regarding ingress versus load balancing for app in microk8s cluster

Tags: load-balancing, kubernetes, ingress, microk8s

I have a seven node microk8s cluster set up on an Ubuntu server in my cellar. multipass shows me I have three IP address per VM since I created these hosts using the bridged network option. I thought having a routable IP might make it easier to expose the VMs and their services to my local network but probably I just made my platform more complex :P

I have succeeded in deploying https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-a-local-kubernetes-with-microk8s "microbot" web app but have not been able to access it using a browser even at the local console. I *can* connect to the app using **curl 10.152.183.40** if I'm ssh'd into a control plane VM.

```
ubuntu@m8s7:~$ microk8s kubectl get all --all-namespaces |grep microbot-service
default        service/microbot-service       NodePort       10.152.183.40    <none>        80:31031/TCP                 34m
```

I'd like to make this (or any web app) run on a 192.168.10.0/24 addresses or at a node's *hostname:port* .

```
Name                    State             IPv4             Image
mk8s0                   Running           10.74.44.144     Ubuntu 21.10
                                          192.168.10.14
                                          10.1.123.64
mk8s1                   Running           10.74.44.172     Ubuntu 21.10
                                          192.168.10.13
                                          10.1.238.128
```

This page https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/fcifi/3.0.1?topic=administering-changing-kubernetes-master-node-ip-address suggests I might be able to make the entire cluster available behind a single IP address but there is no instance of **externalIPs:** when I run **kubectl -n kube-system edit svc** .

Should I be implementing ingress or a load balancer or can I tell k8s to run my app natively on a 192.168.10.0/24 address?

Thanks for any advice.